# MvcRouteAttribute adding to path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Have a MVC5 project that I am using MvcRouteAttributes with.

I have a ClientController.cs that contains:

```
    [Route("Clients/{status?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string status)
    {
        var clients = _context.Clients.ToList();

        return View(clients);
    }

    [Route("ClientDetails/{id}")]
    public ActionResult ClientDetails(int id)
    {
        var client = _context.Clients.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        return View(client);
    }
```

In my _Layout.cshtmlfile,I call the Index action by:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Active", "Index", "Client", new { status = "active" }, null)
```

This generates `<a href="/Clients/active">Active</a>` as expected.

From the view that this link displays, I have additional links generated thus:

```
    @Html.ActionLink(@client.LastName + ", " + @client.FirstName, "ClientDetails/" + @client.Id, "Client")
```

and it generates `<a href="/Client/ClientDetails/1">Clark, Keith</a>`

1) Where is it picking up the `/Client` part, and

2) How would I change it so the href will render like `<a href="/ClientDetails/1">Clark, Keith</a>`

Thanks for your advice,

Keith

Comment: The 2nd one should be `@Html.ActionLink( .... , "ClientDetails", "Client", new { id = client.Id }, null)`

Comment: @Stephen Thank you.  that damn null parameter screws me up everytime.

Comment: Beat me to it, deleted my answer...

Comment: ps - the problem was with where you put the client.Id

Comment: and in question 1, the Client piece is coming from the controller parameter in your actionLink method